# Business account on Google – cancel – what happens with mail, bookmarks, etc?

Tags: google-workspace

I have a Google Business email – so I sign into Gmail using my email address with my own domain.

I don't need the business services any longer.

But I do need my emails, the email account even if it's with a gmail address instead of my domain, and my bookmarks and other things associated with the account.

In other words I'd like to change it so it's a free account.

What happens when I make it a free account? Do I lose my email account, bookmarks, etc?

Or is there a way to keep them?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: my answer is based on what I read at support.google.com and not on personal experience.

First of all you can't downgrade from Business Google Apps to Standard Google Apps (see [Downgrade to Google Apps](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2511952)). Your only option is to delete the account. *"In order to delete a Google Apps account, you must delete all users except for one administrator account. Please note that deleting users will delete all associated data, and is unrecoverable. You will want to [migrate](https://support.google.com/a/answer/100458) all data off of Google Apps before deleting users."* (see [Delete your Google Apps account](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1257646)).